# Resharper foreach tab behavior not working

Tags: c#, foreach, resharper

I'm not sure what happened but the default behavior that I've grown accustomed to has stopped working in regards to foreach followed by TAB.

For example. I type the word foreach. I press TAB. I see this:

[image]

The first template region is the box with COLLECTION in it. Normally I start typing the collection name. When I'm done I type TAB then set the VARIABLE name. etc.

What I actually get is buggy.

For example, after I type in the collection name:

[image]

I press TAB again.

**Expected:** it moves over to VARIABLE so that I can provide a name.

**Actual:** it doesn't move over, and it deletes the closing parenthesis and moves the brace, like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the normal behavior restored?

Note: I do NOT want to restore defaults. That will wipe out dozens of other fine-grained format settings that I have configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: restart visual studio.

For some reason resharper stops responding to normal commands and fixed itself simply by restarting the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some other extensions that are interfering with Resharper.

See this link for more details:

[Speeding up ReSharper (and Visual Studio)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html)